# RSPEc - undefined method `stubs' for #<RoomsController:0x0000010534c050>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise, cancan

I'm trying to write an rspec for my Rooms controller to test permissions with CanCan but keep getting the error in the title. I'm following the steps here under Controller Testing: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities

**room_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RoomsController do

  before(:each) do
    @user_1 = Factory.create(:user, :password => 'password')
    @room_for_user_1 = Room.create(:user_id => @user_1.id)

    @ability = Object.new
    @ability.extend(CanCan::Ability)
    @controller.stubs(:current_ability).returns(@ability)
  end

  describe "Room Permissions" do

    it "should allow a user to join a room" do
      @ability.can :show, @room_for_user_1
      get :show, { :uuid => @room_for_user_1.uuid }
      response.should render_template("show")
    end

  end

end
```

Any advice on how I can get devise + CanCan + RSpec working so I can test the controller? Thanks

Comment: `stubs` doesn't exist, it's `stub!`: http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/stubs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not RSpec syntax, what you want is:

```
@controller.stub!(:current_ability).and_return(@ability)
```

Comment: That that seems to have fixed that error. Any idea why I need to stub in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

### Newer Version 3.8 `allow` Syntax.

```
allow( @controller ).to receive( :current_ability ).and_return( @ability )
```

As per [the Relish 3.8 docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-8/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value).